# How to construct a Scala map and pass as arg into a Scala constructor in Python interpreter?

Tags: java, python, scala, pyspark, py4j

I am working in a Jupyter Notebook with PySpark v2.3.4 which runs on Java 8, Python 3.6 (with py4j==0.10.7), and Scala 2.11, and I have a Scala case class that takes in a `Map` arg as so:

```
case class my_class(arg1: Long, arg2: Map[String, String] = Map.empty)
```

I would like to construct an object from `my_class`, but I cannot quite figure out how to construct the `Map` arg. Below are a couple of my attempts/docs I've followed where `sc` is my SparkContext.

- `sc._jvm.scala.collection.JavaConversions.iterableAsScalaIterable([('hello','world')]).toMap()`

  - [Scala doc for toMap()](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.12/index.html#scala.collection.Iterable@toMap[T,U]:scala.collection.Map[T,U])
- `MapConverter().convert({'a':'b'}, sc._gateway._gateway_client)`

  - [Py4j JavaCollections MapConverter](https://www.py4j.org/advanced_topics.html)
  - compiles but returns a `py4j.java_collections.JavaMap` object and not scala map.
- `sc._jvm.scala.collection.JavaConverters.*`

  - Cannot find any of the methods that exists in its [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.12/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters$)

Those are just a couple of the attempts I've tried so far. Haven't really found good examples on how to do this so any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dug through PySpark's src code and found this -- seems to fix it for now for anybody's reference in the future:

`sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toScalaMap({'hello':'world'})`